# RapidJSON how to query an object using a string variable

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I'm getting an error when I try to query an object using a string variable, but not when I directly use a string.

JSON:
`{"x": "hello"}`

This works:

```
std::cout << document["x"].GetString();
```

This doesn't work:

```
std::string s = "x";
std::cout << document[s].GetString();
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'rapidjson::Document'
  (aka 'GenericDocument<UTF8<> >')
std::cout << document[s].GetString();
                ~~~~~^~
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string'
  (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to 'SizeType' 
(aka 'unsigned int') for 1st argument
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To anyone looking for an answer to my question, I never solved it and started using a new json parser, json11

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
std::cout << document[s.c_str()].GetString();
```

It seems the operator was not overloaded for a std::string but for a C-string.

(Reference for the [c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) member function)

Comment: That got rid of the error, but when the code is run, it fails an assertion in rapidjson/document.h. 
Assertion failed: (false), function operator[], file .../rapidjson/document.h, line 1111.
Abort trap: 6

Comment: After looking at document.h it does not seem to be as simple as I thought at first.
I can't find my way through that template jungle right now.
Sorry